# Is it possible to auto-resize a pane if a node it outside its boundaries in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, autoresize, clipping, pane

i would like to know whether it is possible to auto-resize a pane after adding a node which lies outside the pane boundaries, so that all the pane children are visible on stage. For example, a node with negative x-coordinate such as x = -100,y = 200. I've tried researching about how to do this but all has been in vein. Thanks.

Comment: You want to resize the frame so `x=-100` becomes `x=0`? (which would be moving the frame 100 pixels to the left, then adding 100 to the frame's width to keep it's right side in place) That's a pretty odd thing to do. Mind elaborating on why you'd wanna do something like this?

Comment: The reason i would like to do this is because i need to be able to display an entire  shape/polygon in a pane regardless of its coordinates. Basically enable a pane to auto resize whenever nodes that are outside the visible area are added.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all your children and calculate the total [bounds in parent](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent%28%29), relocate the children so that the top/left position is 0/0, calculate a scale factor depending on the total bounds and the view and then apply [setScaleX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setScaleX%28double%29) and [setScaleY](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setScaleY%28double%29).